# Bulk updating normalized Redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Let's say I have normalized state like this (using normalizr)

```
entities: {
  todos: {
    'aaa': {
      id: 'aaa',
      text: 'Todo A',
      completed: false
    },
    'bbb': {
      id: 'bbb',
      text: 'Todo B',
      completed: false
    },
    'ccc': {
      id: 'ccc',
      text: 'Todo C',
      completed: false
    }
  }
}
```

Then I have an action that fetches array of IDs from the server, that are completed. For that action type, I have reducer like this:

```
const todos = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.FETCH_COMPLETED_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: action.payload.completedIds.map((id) => {
          return {
            [id]: {
              ...state.todos[id],
              completed: true
            }
          }
        })
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

If I recieved an array with ['aaa', 'ccc'] (could be thousands of items in real world app), I want to set "completed" to TRUE on those respective todos in a single action, is it possible?

My current implementation of reducer doesn't work since it returns an array of objects, while original normalized state is object with IDs as key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the modified todos in an object and then update it using the spread syntax like

```
const todos = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.FETCH_COMPLETED_SUCCESS:
      let newTodos = {};
      action.payload.completedIds.forEach((id) => {
          newTodos[id]: {
              ...state.todos[id],
              completed: true
            }
          })
        })
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: {
             ...state.todos,
             ...newTodos
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: This worked, just had to fix a small syntax error.
newTodos[id]: { ... } to newTodos[id] = { ... }

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution for your problem:

```
const todos = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.FETCH_COMPLETED_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: Object.keys(action.payload.completedIds).reduce((previous, current) => {
            previous[current] = {
              ...state.todos[current],
              completed: true
            }
            return previous;
          }, {})
        })
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I used this solution because returns a new object and leaves the original object as it is

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 const todos = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.FETCH_COMPLETED_SUCCESS:
      const newState = {};//New Object
      const filterKeys = Object.keys(state).filter( key=>{
        newState[key]=state[key]; //copy
        return completedIds.indexOf(key)!=-1;
      });
      filterKeys.forEach(key=> newState[key].completed = true);
       return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```